# Evaluating Ruby regular expressions stored in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I am building a tool to keep rewrite rules for all sorts of content into a database table:

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| replace_text | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| replace_with | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| scp          | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

When I process content I just pull all relevant rules (based on the scp field) and run a `<variable>.gsub(replace_text, replace_with)` to change whatever is required.

My question is whether or not it's possible to check if `replace_text` contains a valid regexp and use that instead of replacing the plain text contents of the column?

Because basically:

```
 "Sometimes it's best to keep things simple".gsub('/[aeiou]/',"x")
```

outputs "Sometimes it's best to keep things simple"

while:

```
"Sometimes it's best to keep things simple".gsub(eval('/simple/'),"x")
```

or

```
"Sometimes it's best to keep things simple".gsub(/simple/,"x")
```

Output what I need:

"Sometimes it's best to keep things x"

So basically what I'm looking for is a way to find out if a string contains a valid regular expression or not.

I've searched around and it seems regular expressions cannot be validated with other regular expressions. Using `eval()` all the time is not an option because the variable may not always contain a regular expression, but just some plain text to remove/replace.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Regexp` class to generate regexp according to the store pattern in text.

```
record = Record.last
record.replace_test.gsub Regexp.new(record.replace_with), 'x'
```

Comment: @NickM My pleasure. You can also check Wayne's answer which is more considerate.

Answer (score 3):

Given a string containing a valid regular expression, `Regexp.new` returns successfully:

```
Re1.9.3-p484 :001 > Regexp.new("asdf")
 => /asdf/
```

Given a string containing an invalid regular expression, `Regexp.new` raises RegexpError:

```
1.9.3-p484 :002 > Regexp.new("asdf)")
RegexpError: unmatched close parenthesis: /asdf)/
```

therefore:

```
def pattern_to_regexp(pattern)
  Regexp.new(pattern)
rescue RegexpError
  nil
end
alias valid_regexp_pattern? pattern_to_regexp
```

returns a Regexp if possible, or a nil if the pattern string is not a valid regular expression.

Since a Regexp is truthy, and nil is falsy, `valid_regexp_pattern` is the same method.

To use it:

```
s.gsub(pattern_to_regexp(pattern) || pattern, replacement)
```

This works because String#gsub will take either a Regexp or a String as the search argument.

Comment: Nice rescue. You are considerate!

Comment: Interesting approach, I will try something similar. Example above does not work though, if I do something like Regexp.new("asdf") the output is /asdf/ so basically it takes the junk and turns it into a regular expression.

Comment: @NickM That is because "asdf" is a valid regular expression.  But, as `gsub("asdf", "replacement")` is identical to `gsub(/asdf/, "replacement")`, what's the harm?

Comment: Yep, you are right. I got it to work like a charm last night. Thank you Wayne and Billy! This baby will process several million records every hour, thanks to your help it will be much more powerful with regexp!

Answer (score 1):

> So basically what I'm looking for is a way to find out if a string
>   contains a valid regular expression or not.

try this:

```
str = "Sometimes it's best to keep things simple"
if str =~ /simple/
 #do your thing
end
```

You can try match too:

```
do_something if str.match('simple')
```

Answer (score 0):

addition to Billy's answer you can also use following

```
record.replace_test.gsub /#{record.replace_with}/, 'x'
```